# why when i try to get the feed of a facebook group through the API, I can't always see the photo in a post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In the same group there are some posts with photos that I can get through API, but there are others posts with photos where I can't get the photo, I can see only the text. ( the same thing appen also for the comments in the group). 
Apparently seems to be not logic the reason, because I don't think is a privicy problem.
Some help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the modifier .filter(stream) to the field you're looking for. 
Such as

```
graph.facebook.com/v2.1/{object_id}?fields=feed.filter(stream)
```

This will force all the nodes/edges to return. Facebook likes to "hide" some that it's "Top Story" algorithm determines has a low score.

The documentation is very poor on this modifier.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it seems that there isn't any difference